# Watching a provider inside another provider

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I have a NotifierProvider that holds the value of a String:

```
class ImportantString extends Notifier<String> {
  @override
  String build() {
    return '1';
  }

  void update(String newValue) {
    state = newValue;
  }
}

final importantStringProvider = NotifierProvider<ImportantString, String>(ImportantString.new);
```

I’m listening to this change (using ref.watch) on another Provider:

```
final remoteRepositoryProvider = Provider<RemoteRepository>((ref) {
  return RemoteRepository(
    dio: Dio(BaseOptions(baseUrl: ref.watch(importantStringProvider))),
  );
});
```

The app starts first with the '1'.

Then I update the importantStringProvider to '2':

```
ref.read(importantStringProvider.notifier).update('2');
```

This reflects everywhere well enough, during widget builds etc. I get the updated value '2'.

But on the remoteRepositoryProvider  that is defined right above I still continue getting the old value 1 no matter if I use ref.watch or ref.read (not preferred as to Riverpod docs).
Wouldn’t ref.watch guarantee us the up to date values?

Also tried to listen to changes using ref.listen like this:

```
final remoteRepositoryProvider = Provider<RemoteRepository>((ref) {
  String newImportantString = ref.read(importantStringProvider);
  ref.listen(importantStringProvider, (_, state) {
    newImportantString = state;
    log('updated');
  }, fireImmediately: true);
  return RemoteRepository(
    dio: Dio(BaseOptions(baseUrl: newImportantString)),
  );
});
```

But I never reach the 'update' string to be printed onto the console nor are the values updated using the newImportantString update inside `ref.listen`.